# java applet could not save file to local pc

Tags: java, ios, applet, save

My applet is running on Java 7 Update 25. I'm trying to save a report from my applet to my local computer but I keep having the following error:

```java
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Test" "write")
      at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
      at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
      at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have granted all permissions in my `java.policy` file, but it isn't working.

For testing purpose, my pc is using a windows environment. It acts as a server (weblogic, http) as well as client (to test applet).

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Is your applet digitally signed?

Comment: yes, digitally signed

Comment: Try to save it on another drive except then C: drive.

Comment: tried but didn't work

Comment: what about writing to like c:\temp or an equivalent?